# widget text is too long, thus it is not displayed fully

Tags: python, layout, widget, ipywidgets

As you can see, the variable multiplier_to_change_intensity_of_noise is not displayed fully, while I would like it to be displayed on one line and have the slider next to it

```
x = np.random.uniform(0,5,100)
noise = np.random.normal(size=100)

def f(multiplier_to_change_intensity_of_noise):
    y = 2 * x + w * noise
    plt.scatter(x,y)

widgets.interact(f, multiplier_to_change_intensity_of_noise = (-5,5,0.1))
```

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1J0G.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
label = widget.Label(value = "the description")
WIDGET = widget.floatslider()
```

make sure that the floatslider has no description

```
name = HBox((label,WIDGET))
```

Comment: Please explain more of what your code does.